# Hibernate projects and Building with maven

Tags: hibernate, maven-2

I'm trying to build a relative easy project and include Hibernate with maven. I'm trying to use the *latest* version of Hibernate (3.5.4-Final).

It seems that the JBoss folks have changed their maven repository recently, and I'm having some problems getting my maven build to work. I have found a lot of information on the web and here, but nothing seems to work quite right... Lots of information I have found does not let me get the latest version of Hibernate.

I have the following repository defined in my pom.xml:

```
<repository>
    <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
    <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
    <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
</repository>
```

I have the following dependency defined in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This seems to download some of the dependencies, but not enough to build.

I get the following error:

```
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate/3.5.4-Final/hibernate-3.5.4-Final.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.5.4-Final' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

I've read the page JBoss says to read [Maven Getting Started - Users](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Users), and to be honest it doesn't make any sense to me. It says to put stuff in my settings.xml. I would like to put information in my pom.xml and not require everyone to modify the settings.xml. I'm hardly a maven expert. I just really want to know what to put in my pom.xml file to get this to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding JBoss repository to m2eclipse, no latest Hibernate version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678892/adding-jboss-repository-to-m2eclipse-no-latest-hibernate-version), [How to compile hibernate project with maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999077/how-to-compile-hibernate-project-with-maven), [Unable to compile and create maven project for hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068804/unable-to-compile-and-create-maven-project-for-hibernate) etc. Welcome to SO but, please, do a search before posting.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
    <!-- <type>jar</type> is implied here -->
</dependency>
```

is just a pom, while you are trying to reference it as a jar. So to reference it, you would have to do it like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

This would grab this pom's transitive dependencies, but not the artifact itself.
However, the pom [only lists modules](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/hibernate/hibernate/3.5.4-Final/hibernate-3.5.4-Final.pom), not dependencies, as it's the root pom for hibernate. It won't help you, leave it alone.

So what you really want is either

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
</dependency>
```

(for classic hibernate) or

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
</dependency>
```

(for the jpa2 provider)

Answer (score 4):

Well I found the answer...

This will get the stuff you need. From the page quoted above, add the following to your pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
        <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
        <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Here is the dependency you need:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You don't need to declare a `pluginRepository` to use Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks, just saved me a bunch of debugging for the exact same problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

JBoss have started synchronising their own repo with Maven central as [posted on the JBoss community blog](http://community.jboss.org/en/build/blog/2011/05/24/rsync-jbossorg-to-maven-central) , therefore `hibernate` artifacts are now available without the need to add the JBoss repository to your `pom.xml` or repository manager.

[Search result for hibernate-core](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.hibernate%22%20AND%20a%3A%22hibernate-core%22):

[image: search result for hibernate-core]

To add the Hibernate Core 3.6.3 to your project, just add the following snippet to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```